# How to properly animate code for a three-body system?

Tags: python, animation, physics, gravity

I am trying to write a program that animates the simulated motion of three objects and I have found that the easiest way for me to achieve that was to define the motion of the objects with a looping function that populates the positional arguments a1,a2,a3 for the three different objects. Each "a" is a list of the position of the objects as they move through time; a1=[[x0,y0],[x1,y1],[x2,y2],...]

```
#Function populating position data#

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 1, figsize = (10,10))
axes.set_ylim(-1.5, 1.5)
axes.set_xlim(-1.5, 1.5)
plt.style.use("ggplot")

def animate(j):
        axes.plot(a1[0],a1[1], color="red", linewidth=1)
        axes.plot(a2[0],a2[1], color="gray", linewidth=0.5)
        axes.plot(a3[0],a3[1], color="blue", linewidth=1)
        
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=10)
plt.show()
```

For some reason, all I get is a static straight line which doesn't correspond to the positions of any of the objects defined by the position lists a1, a2, or a3. I've combed through the data populating function, and have not found any problems with populating the positions of the objects, so I am assuming that I must have messed up my coding of the animation function. Can someone please lend me a hand and guide me in the right direction?

Edit: I can add the function populating the position data if its needed, but I am just trying to figure out how to animate motion through time along x and y, given positional data.

Comment: i'm guessing that your positions need to be a function of j, can you provide an executable sample? so like `a1[j][0]` or `a1[j, 0]`

Comment: I tried a1[j,0] and got a TypeError: "list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple," and a1[j][0] produces an empty plot and makes the spyder IDE stop responding until I close the empty plot. I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: look at this https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/